# How to use order by with modified column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

There is a Table with a age-column. The Value of this column is a varchar because the age of persons under the age of 1 is saved in months with an additional 'm' (9 Month old -> '9m')

I know that this is generally a bad idea and one should rather persist the date of birth, but in this case the age refers to the age on a specific day in history - and additionally this is part of a lesson and the whole point is learning how to treat "weird" data.

My first idea was to put a leading zero on all ages which are not purely numeric:

```
SELECT * 
FROM db 
ORDER BY REPLACE(age, (IF ISNUMERIC(age) age ELSE CONCAT('0', age))) DESC;
```

However this is not a valid SQL-statement and neither are my other attempts.
The question is: How can I adjust the value used for `ORDER BY` without altering the db?

Another approach would be to select only the rows with a purely numeric age value and a separate select for the remaining rows order both of them separately and combine them afterwards.

My take on this was the following:

```
(SELECT name, age 
 FROM titanic 
 WHERE ISNUMERIC(age) 
 ORDER BY age DESC) 
UNION 
(SELECT name, age 
 FROM titanic 
 WHERE NOT ISNUMERIC(age) 
 ORDER BY age);
```

This is in fact valid or at least it gives me a result. But in the result I can't really see what happened to the order, it looks like the `UNION` undos everything.

Thanks in advance, will take any tip or even just the name of the function/method I should look into!

Comment: You probably could do it with `CASE WHEN … ELSE …` structure instead of `IF`

Comment: Tried that one too, gives me an error with ELSE - then I tried two WHEN cases without the ELSE, same kind of error

Comment: If you store the age of people in a database, the data will rot as time goes by. Store the birthday.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

SELECT name, age
FROM titanic
ORDER BY isnumeric(age), age

Answer (score 0):

I would use "Case When" structure with some transformations in the "Order by" to get the total number of months for both types of ages.

```
Select name, age
From tbl
Where age SIMILAR TO '[1-9][0-9]*' Or
      age SIMILAR TO '[1-9][0-2]?m'
Order by Case When age SIMILAR TO '[1-9][0-2]?m' Then Substring(age,1,CHAR_LENGTH(age)-1)::int
              When age SIMILAR TO '[1-9][0-9]*' Then age::int * 12 End
```

Comment: I addressed exactly what you explain here right up there in the question … it’s not a Option

Comment: @ningelsohn Why It's not a option after all, it works.

Answer (score 0):

First off storing age is a poor idea, you must update every row regularly, in this case at least monthly. Storing it as string turns a poor idea into a terrible idea. Not only do you have the maintenance, it is not straight forward nor is it straight forward to insert it. Instead store date-of-birth as a timestamp or date. You can then quickly get age (via the [age](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html)) you can then use the [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function on the resulting interval at whatever level is desired. If you absolutely must present age with text indicator for either years/months (or even days) you create a view that derives the appropriate value. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a34a79102c9aa794f61ff8281071229))

```
create or replace view titanic as 
    select name "Name"
         , case when extract( year from age(dob))::integer > 0 then to_char (extract( year from age(dob)), '999') || ' years'
                when extract( month from age(dob))::integer> 0 then to_char (extract( month from age(dob)), '99') || ' months'
                else to_char (extract( day  from age(dob)),'99') || ' days'
           end "Age"
      from titanic_tbl;
```

Comment: Thank you - honestly, I am fully aware of the problems with the age column. I could have asked a more generalized question about ordering a string after manipulating it without actually changing the value in the database. In my case I want to order by the age after casting it to a number if it’s numeric. If it’s not I want to remove the non-numeric chars (in this case just removing „m“ is fine) and divide the number by 12. 9m should result in 0.75 so that the order is correct. I am currently on vacation and will take a detailed look into your suggestion when I am back home - thanks!

Comment: No worry. As long as you are aware of the issues storing age. I have just seen its implementation (and the resulting needed rewrite) on a few occasions .  It is just one of the things I'll point out when I see it.   But your comment is a far better description of the issue that the actual question. Always give careful thought to your questions for someone totally unaware of what you are trying to solve.